# Programmatically obtain the unique session identity of browser session (Dash/Flask)

Tags: python-3.x, flask, redis, plotly-dash, session-state

I'm using Dash (AKA a Flask backend.)

Dash server recognizes a running browser session, such that if you refresh the page any data is maintained (for example in a persistent dropdown or the `Store()` method [State data, I.e. `dcc.Store(id = "variable", storage_type='session')`].) The STore() data is persistent throughout the session by using the `storage_type='session'` parameter...and thus survives until the browser window is closed.

**Is there a way to programmatically obtain some sort of uniquely identifying session ID from the browser session from within the Dash app (with Python code)? *For example*, if a user was connected to the Dash server via a browser, and the *Dash server app was restarted*, it could detect that 'this browser session was connected before the restart" and obtain the same unique ID?** Is the session data held in a cookie? If it is, I can't find it in the browser cookies.

It doesn't matter if it's the actual same session ID actually being used under the good by Dash/Flask. Just that the running dash app itself can tell that this browser session had been previously connected to it after the Dash app gets restarted.

**I want to use the identifier as a key for external data stored in a Redis DB**. The data is generated and stored in a multiprocessing thread started by the Dash app. I dont know if I could use `flask_cache`ing with redis from within the multiprocessing thread.

I don't want to manually create session IDs (I.e. using `session_id = uuid.uuid4()`, since that would be reset every time the dash app is restarted...defeating the goal.